# common roots of polynomials in Galois fields and the complex numbers

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, finite-fields

Is the following true or false? If two polynomials of degree $n>2$ have a common root in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is prime and $n|(p-1)$, then they have a common root in $\mathbb{C}$? If so, why?

(I am not a student and this is not an exam question.)

Comment: The question is a bit strange because the polynomials lose a part of their identity when you view them having coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ as opposed to $\Bbb{C}$. For example $x-7$ and $x-2$ share the root $x=2$ in $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$ but obviously have no common zeros in $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Anyway, it shouldn't be difficult to construct other kinds of examples, where similar things happen. Still with $p=5$. The polynomial $x^2+1$ has zeros $\pm2$, sharing the root $x=2$ with $(x-1)(x-2)$, but again they have no common complex zeros. What exactly do you want to see examples of?

Comment: That's why I said that $n>2$; I could't see any obvious examples for $n=3$ for example. I'm particularly interested in common zeros of $x^n - 1$ and $(x+1)^n - 1$.in $\mathbb{C}$, shared roots exist iff $3|n$. By computer, shared roots exist in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for sufficiently large primes $p$ iff $3|n$. Correlation is not causation but...

Comment: If two monic polynomials with integer coefficients share a common complex zero, then they share a common factor $d(x)$ from $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. Reducing $d(x)$ modulo any prime $p$ is then a non-trivial polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, so it always has its zeros in some extension field of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. Whether some of those zeros are in the prime field is somewhat coincidental (but will happen with a certain positive probability unless there is a very specific reason not to).

Comment: The degree requirement ($n>2$) is a non-problem. Consider $(x^2+1)^2$ and $(x-1)^2(x-2)^2$
over $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{C}$. But your specific pair of polynomials is a bit more interesting.

Comment: Roots of unity in the fields $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ give plenty of examples. Consider that all the non-zero elements of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ are zeros of $x^{p-1}-1$. Hence $x^{p-1}-1$ and $(x+1)^{p-1}-1$ share $p-2$ roots in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. For all $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The result is false:-

The polynomials $x^3+1$ and $x^3+5x$ have common root $3$ over $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ but no common root over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Obviously I meant that the coefficients should come from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Grumbledore But the elements of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ are not complex numbers, taking us back to the point of my first comment under your question.

Comment: OK, we've established that it's not true in general. As I mentioned above, I'm most interested in the polynomials $x^n - 1$ and $(x+1)^n - 1$. I'd like to prove that if $n|(p-1)$, then $GF(p)$ has consecutive $n$th roots of unity, then $3|n$. I was hoping to lift the question into $\mathbb{C}$, but that's looking more difficult than I expected. Thanks for all the help.